# Wrap around legacy .NET Project in .Net 4.5 project

Tags: c#, .net

I have a legacy project (written and compiled in .Net 2.0), it is huge, and lots of other projects are referencing that. It is planned to decommission it, but it will take some time. I'd like to introduce new version of that project where any new functionalities will be put and .NET 4.5.1 will be introduced. 
I want to keep all the old functionality of old project to be accessible from the new Project2 and only. Without converting old project from .Net 2.0, without any need to reference Project1 dll when Project2 is already referenced.

I am aware that projects compiled for .NET lower than 4.5.1 won't be able to reference Project2 (because of higher .net incompatibility), Project2 is a part of new world created to abandon the legacy code.

How can I achieve that? Currently I am inheriting all public classes (~150 of them), it works but still I need to reference dll of the old project.

Comment: you can't as you stated.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an intermediary assembly which references your old assembly and it's newer replacement.  Then from any future projects, it could just reference the intermediary assembly.  That would allow you to work at your own pace to slowly replace functionality in the old assembly with functionality in the new assembly while not affecting higher-level code that references it.

Comment: hmm, like a bridge between both of those... I will check that. I thought that maybe there is some magic technology that can allow me to achieve my goal and I don't know it, but as we can see, there is life, not magic.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

1. Create a new solution
2. Add a project to this solution and set its .Net version to 2 (project 1)
3. Add another project to this solution and set its .Net version to 4.5 (project 2)
4. Yo can add the classes (source code files) from project 1 into project 2 by adding 'Existing Items' and making sure that you add them as link (click on the down arrow on the 'Add'button in the open file dialog). Or you could just copy the code files into project 2 (duplicating the code)

Each project will have a different DLL name and can be in different version

Comment: For linked project there is still need to reference the linked DLL in parallel with the new project, I think. Yeah, we don't want code to duplicate.

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but versioning there is completely not a problem, all .Net above 2.0 can use most of stuff from 2.0 version. Problems is about hiding the Project1 from the user.